# Unable to Align ImageView by code

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created a `RelativeLayout` where I want to align 9 Imageviews according to my taste. I first tried to do so in **XML** but because the margins will change according to different screen size I thought doing it by code will be much easier. They should appear like a 3X3 square matrix so that first image view will have 2 to right and 2 below it.

**What I Did:-**

First initialised the imageview in XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/pagefw" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView8"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:minWidth="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cross" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I changed the position of the 1st Imageview by code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv1.getLayoutParams());
    lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    iv1.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

And then aligned the rest imageviews according to the 1st imageview.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sec = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv2.getLayoutParams());
    sec.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.imageView1);
    sec.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.imageView1);
    iv2.setLayoutParams(sec);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams thr = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv3.getLayoutParams());
    thr.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.imageView1);
    thr.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView2);
    iv3.setLayoutParams(thr);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fou = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv4.getLayoutParams());
    fou.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.imageView1);
    iv4.setLayoutParams(fou);
```

I tried to do so with first 4 imageview to see it works or not and it didn't.

**What I am getting:-**
Only the first imageview appears at the exact place the rest are appearing anyother places.

So whats wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend using table view instead for this task. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546572/android-layouts-tableview

Comment: Yeah...that's what I wanted to do lastly but I am just stuck at whats really wrong with my code!?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sec = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv2.getLayoutParams());
sec.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.imageView1);
sec.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView1);
iv2.setLayoutParams(sec);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams thr = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv3.getLayoutParams());
thr.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.imageView1);
thr.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView2);
iv3.setLayoutParams(thr);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams fou = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(iv4.getLayoutParams());
fou.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageView1);
iv4.setLayoutParams(fou);
```